# Change Azure VM Update Policy

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2019

I have multiple VMs running on Azure but noticed that the Windows update policy differs. Unfortunately, I cannot locate the setting in the Azure portal. Below is a screenshot from the first VM that has the option "Never check for updates" configured.

[image]

The other VM has the option "Install updates automatically using Windows Update" configured.

[image]

When I click on the it, it tells me that the settings are managed by our organization because of Azure. However, where do I change that? I cannot find anything in the portal and I have been searching for hours. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by opening sconfig and the option 5 lets you select the windows update setting. Restart the virtual machine and then it takes some time until the changes are reflected in the server manager. For me it still showed the old option for quite some time but it will change, trust me.

**Edit:**

After running a manual update check, it reflected the changes in the server manager.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot locate the setting in the Azure portal.

There is no setting in the Azure Portal.

While Windows Update settings on the Server OS and Azure Update Management cooperate, they are effectively totally independent of one another.

All Azure Update Management really does is poke the operating system with a stick and tell it to install updates, how the OS goes about that can be effected by certain Windows Update settings on the OS.

See my answer to this post here to for more detail about how the local OS settings work, and suggestions for configuring them to work with Azure Update Management:

[Windows Update showing "Some settings are managed by your organization" on Azure Windows Server 2019 VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/1041307/windows-update-showing-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization-on-azure/1049744?noredirect=1#comment1367055_1049744)